# Clojure generating matrices

Tags: matrix, clojure

I am going throw the Clojure for Machine Learning book and I dont understand one part of one function.

```
 (defn square-mat
  "Creates a square matrix of size n x n whose
   elements are all e. Accepts an option argument
   for the matrix implementation"
   [n e & {:keys [implementation]
    :or {implementation :persistent-vector}}]
   (let [repeater #(repeat n %)]
   (matrix implementation (-> e repeater repeater))))

(defn id-mat
 "Creates an identity matrix of n x n size"
 [n]
 (let [init (square-mat :clatrix n 0)
  identity-f (fn [i j n]
               (if (= i j) 1 n))]
 (cl/map-indexed identity-f init)))
```

In this second function, I don't understand this part (if  ( =  i  j) than 1 else n). Why else n? n is size

Comment: as far as i can see, the `init` matrix is a square, filled with zero values, and for identity matrix, you need to set the diagonal (rowidx == columnidx) to ones. So that's what it does: map-indexed returns a new matrix, from the old one, applying identity-fn to each `[i j value-at-i-j]`, so when `i != j` it just leaves 0 (since all values (n) are 0), while for `i == j` (diagonal position indices) returns 1,

Comment: Maybe this is just a copy and paste error, but be aware, that your call to square-mat has different parameters than what the defn expects)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Look at the definition](https://github.com/tel/clatrix/blob/master/src/clatrix/core.clj) of `clatrix/map-indexed`. It takes a function of three arguments (the row index, the column index, and the element in that position), and a matrix.

In the inner function `(fn [i j n] (if (= i j) 1 n)`, `n` is bound not to the number of the rows in the matrix, but to the value in the position (i, j) - which happens to be always zero because the `init` matrix was initialized with zeros.

Looks like the book is using a very confusing notation (since `n` is bound to the number of rows in the matrix in the outer function, it would be better to name the third argument of the inner function `x` or somehow else), but the function should still work.